# Проблема min-width в Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы содержимое тега HTML то бишь всего сайта, открывалось одинаково на всех разрешениях браузера, т.е. ширина сайта принимала ширину окна браузера.

В Chrome все отлично работает, достаточно задать `min-width` для тега HTML, но в Firefox и Safari это не работает, как быть?
Может я что-то упускаю?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html stlye="min-width:1400px;">
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="very-big-block" style="width:1300px;height:1300px;background: red;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не понял связи между проблемой и min-width. Ширина с окно браузера задаётся вообще-то через `width: 100vw`

Comment: Автор, покажи те часть кода, css и html, где не работает свойство min-width

Comment: В первую очередь надо сюда добавить код, что бы людям понятно было, что да как там ты творишь, а потом задавать вопрос....

Comment: К сожалению код привести не могу, вставил пример. В хроме через дебаггер мобильных устройств мы увидим красный квадрат по центру экрана мобильного устройства, а в firefox нет

Comment: `<html stlye="min-width:1400px;">`  это что за конструкция? не трогай `html body` никогда

Comment: @Air А как тогда добиться того же эффекта?

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не имей привычку трогать `html и body`. Ну даже `body` еще можно, но очень не желательно. То что ты хочешь сделать лучше делать через обертку. Создаешь `div` можешь назвать как угодно, но обычно это или `root или wrapper`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1400px;
  background: green;
}

.very-big-block {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="very-big-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не согласен. Html и body замечательно трогаются.

Answer (score 0):

Значение -moz-fit-content — задает ширину оптимальную для содержимого.

Для min-width это -moz-min-content, для max-width это -moz-max-content, а для width это большее значение между -moz-min-content и минимальным из -moz-max-content и -moz-available.

Пример:

`div {
min-width:-moz-fit-content;
}`